# Array .indexOf returning -1 despite match

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, indexof

I'm writing a flexible search algorithm for a portion of my XML file. I have this exact same method working flawlessly elsewhere, thus why this is driving me batty.

Here is the section of my function that I'm having trouble with.

```
var searchResults:Array = [];
var r:Array = [];

//Other code...

var classSplit:Array = inClass.split("-");
var profs:Array = getCourseProfs(classSplit[0], classSplit[1]);
trace(searchResults + "-vs-" + profs);

for each(var si:String in searchResults)
{
    trace(si + " is at index " + profs.indexOf(si));
    trace(profs);
    if(r.indexOf(si) == -1 && profs.indexOf(si) != -1)
    {
        r.push(si);
        trace(r);
    }
}
```

And here is the output for a particular run's trace statements (from the above code).

```
GABIOMA1,GABIOMA1-vs-GABIOMA1,MITCHKA1,GIBSOCA1
GABIOMA1 is at index -1
GABIOMA1,MITCHKA1,GIBSOCA1
GABIOMA1 is at index -1
GABIOMA1,MITCHKA1,GIBSOCA1
Final:
```

As you can see, the function has two results in the searchResults array (of strings). They're both identical since I haven't yet sorted out duplicate search results. "GABIOMA1,GABIOMA1"

Then, I'm comparing that to an array "profs" with these three values: "GABIOMA1,MITCHKA1,GIBSOCA1"

You can see the matching result in index 0 of profs. However, as you see from the next line, `profs.indexOf(si)' when`si` is "GABIOMA1" incorrectly returns "-1".

I can write a workaround in a heartbeat, but I need to know why indexOf has decided to bork.

EDIT: Even more infurating, the code in the other branch of the IF statement from this works like a charm...

```
for each(var s:String in searchResults)
{
    if(r.indexOf(s) == -1)
    {
        r.push(s);
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: This is my WORKING workaround. As you can see, all of the arrays are working properly.

```
for each(var si:String in searchResults)
{
    var match:Boolean = false;
    for each(var pi:String in profs)
    {
        if(si == pi)
        {
            pr.push(si);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `match == true;` should be `match=true;` (edit2: line8)

Comment: Hm, thanks for catching that. (Comment upvote.) [For those reading along, it doesn't yet answer the question, though.]

Comment: Updated my workaround code again for efficiency. Question remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Given your `trace(profs)` returns a single string, your array contains a string `GABIOMA1,MITCHKA1,GIBSOCA1` as a *single entity*, that's why your index of `GABIOMA1` returns -1. You need to do split by comma within `getCourseProfs()` to get your `GABIOMA1` as a separate string.

UPDATE: I have tested with the following:

```
    var t:Array = ['GABIOMA1', 'MISCHKA1', 'GIBSOCA1'];
    trace(t);
    trace(t.indexOf('GABIOMA1'));
    var a:Array = ['MITCHKA1', 'GABIOMA1\x00'];
    for each(var si:String in a) trace(si, 'is at index', t.indexOf(si));
```

This gave me an expected result of -1 for either element of `a`, and expected trace results as in your example, however, equality test fails. Please try trimming the `searchResults` strings prior to checking for `indexOf()`.

A side note: placing a `\x00` as the first char of a string produces different results for tracing! `trace(si, 'is at index', t.indexOf(si));` results in an empty string displayed in place of `si` like this: `is at index -1`, while `trace(si + ' is at index ' + t.indexOf(si));` results in full string displayed: `GABIOMA1 is at index -1`. So carefully check either string for non-printable symbols, it's likely there is some hidden zero char that screws `indexOf()`.

Comment: No, profs has multiple entries. Trace returns arrays like that.

Comment: My current working code is in EDIT 2. As you can see, since that works, profs is most certainly a proper array, not just a string as you proposed.